# Outlook using python win32com to iterate mails from specific daterange only

Tags: python-3.x, outlook, win32com

I am trying to get a list of all the senders of the mails sent in a particular date range from a folder of shared inbox. The folder is having 18000+ mails in total. The code I have is using the date range to filter and append the name of the senders in a list.

I am able to get all the mail in the folder and then append the senders name to a list by filtering out the mail based out of the date range provided by the user as an input.

```
import win32com.client
import datetime

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
recip = outlook.CreateRecipient("example@example.com")
folder=outlook.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip,6).Folders("Nothing")
messages = folder.Items
first = messages.GetFirst()
senders = []
#edu_users = []

while first:
    date = int(datetime.datetime.strftime(first.SentOn, r'%m%d%Y'))
    print(date)
    if date >= start and date <= end:
        print("In Range")
        if first.SenderEmailType == "EX":
            senders.append(first.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress)
        else:
            senders.append(first.SenderEmailAddress)
    first = messages.GetNext()
```

The issue is that because of the huge amount of the mails present in the folder, python takes too much time to read all the mails and filter out the mail from specific date. Is there any way by which I can make sure that the script starts reading the mail from the start date and stop when the mail is out of end date range and not start from the first mail in the folder and go till last mail in the folder ?

Comment: @Ben.Tyeah that was if only, code got scrambled while posting the question. Updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Never apply conditions directly in your code - this is like running a SELECT statement without a WHERE clause- your DB admin won't be happy (or worse).

Use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict` - let the server do the heavy lifting. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.find

Answer (score 0):

Like Dmitry already posted, you need to use `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods to extract the required items from a folder and then deal with them. Read more about them in the following articles and find a sample code:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Note, the `Find` or `FindNext` methods are faster than filtering if there are a small number of items. The `Restrict` method is significantly faster if there is a large number of items in the collection, especially if only a few items in a large collection are expected to be found.

Also, you may consider using the [AdvancedSearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb219884(v=office.12)) method of the `Application` class which performs a search based on a specified DAV Searching and Locating (DASL) search string. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the Items property of the Folder class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the IsInstantSearchEnabled property of the Store class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the Stop method of the Search class.